# Azure Functions: Compiling, Debugging, Intellisense VS2017

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

We are looking for a way to do development of Azure functions inside of VS2017. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooling for Visual Studio 2017 is still under development. You can track the current status in [this github issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/201).

UPDATE: The Preview of Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Azure Functions are now available for download. The [blog post explains the tools, requirements, and has a link to the download](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/). Note that it only works in VS 15.3 Preview, not in earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer to develop [precompiled functions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/) and publish as a web application.

You can get some helpful intellisense for `host.json` and `function.json` by using the json schemas http://json.schemastore.org/function & http://json.schemastore.org/host