# Unable to load migrated Azure functions project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I have developed an Azure Functions project in Visual Studio 2015 (a project with a `.funproj` file extension). Now I want to migrate it to Visual Studio 2017 but when I try, VS does not load the project.

Why is the migration failing and how can I complete it manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Functions: Compiling, Debugging, Intellisense VS2017](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43378462/azure-functions-compiling-debugging-intellisense-vs2017)

Comment: @Mikhail, I disagree. This is a specific question about migrating .funproj projects from VS2015 to VS2017 so different from that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Functions tooling for Visual Studio 2017 is still work in progress. They are expected to be announced during upcoming Build event.

Watch this [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/201) for status.

UPDATE: The Preview of Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Azure Functions are now available for download. The [blog post explains the tools, requirements, and has a link to the download](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/). Note that it only works in VS 15.3 Preview, not in earlier versions.

As far as I know, there's no migration tooling available per se, so you'd have to start from a blank project and then convert your script to static class and `function.json` to proper bindings.

Comment: This solution does not work for me, unfortunately. I just installed Visual Studio 2017 v15.3 Preview with the latest Tools for Azure Functions extension. I still get the same "Unsupported" migration error message.

Comment: @urig You can't migrate the old project I guess, you have to create a new one from scratch

Comment: you might want to update your answer to reflect that.

Comment: That's right, you have to create a new project from scratch. We don't plan to have any migration support.