# Azure-functions: I cannot choose consumption plan

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I was following the steps as described in [Publishing a .NET class library as a Function App](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app) and for the most part I got everything set up and tested.

I have one last pending issue. When I try to publish the app, trying to select an existing "Microsoft Azure App Service" yields no results (on all my subscriptions) even though I have a few existing ones (from previous tests manually created in the portal).

On the other hand, if I try to create a new one (from VS) I am not allowed to choose a "Consumption plan", only Bx, Sx and Px. I tried creating an app service on consumption plan manually in the portal, but I was not offered this option.

Is "consumption plan" a thing of the past? Or is something wrong with my subscription?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consumption plan is not a thing of the past. On the portal, I think you can't create it from "New App Service Plan" dialog. Instead, try creating "Function App" and then pick "Consumption Plan" in "Hosting Plan" drop down.

As to your issues with Visual Studio - I had that while using Azure SDK which was out of date. So try updating it to a new version.

Comment: (Un)fortunately, any Azure SDK updates are delivered directly with the VS2017 setup. It was only yesterday that I installed a 15.2 update for VS2017. I suppose I received any Azure SDK updates along with this. Downloading manual updates for Azure SDK in VS 2017 seems impossible.

Comment: As for consumption plan, you are very right. I can still create this in the portal although it is a pain. I don't think it should be so difficult to locate the functionality. Thanks.

Comment: @wpfwannabe Ah, VS2017 v. 15.2 has no proper tooling for Function Apps, you should stick to VS2015 or try 15.3 preview if you feel like. See [my reply here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43776713/1171619)

Comment: Okay, thanks to your help I managed to this in the end. Indeed, I had to revert to VS2015. Also I had to manually create a function app on consumption plan in the portal, then export the publish profile and import it into VS. From this point on, it was all smooth sailing...